# How can i modify isolinux.cfg?

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader

I used [SARDU](http://www.sarducd.it/) for multi-bootable live DVD. first I made live usb which made perfectly in which I can modified. then i try to made dvd in which i can't modify `isolinx.cfg` but in usb i can modify `syslinux.cfg`. How can i modify `isolinux.cfg` then how to boot cd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DVD is a write-once media. When the file `isolinux.cfg` has been "burned" to the DVD disk, there is no way to change it (well, you could scratch it away with a tiny pin ...)

You could use an overlay filesystem but that won't help because the boot loader doesn't support it (the file system needs the kernel, so the boot loader would need to start the kernel first to read its own config file).

**[EDIT]** One solution is to create copy the files from the DVD somewhere, make the changes and create a new DVD image (iso file) from that.

Next, make sure that the changes made it into the image (`mount -o loop file.iso /mnt` and then look at the files under `/mnt`. Don't forget to replace `file.iso` with the correct name of the ISO/DVD image file on your hard disk!!)

If that is OK, create a bootable USB stick with the DVD image. This way, you can test that the image actually boots without wasting DVDs.

When everything works, burn a DVD.

Comment: Sardu provide iso image. but after modifying that iso image can't stay bootable

Comment: I would suggest to forget about booting from DVD. It's slower than USB, you can't make changes to the boot files. The only advantage of the DVD is security: Since you can't modify files, no attacker can compromise it.

Comment: due to security i choose DVD rather than USB

Comment: What do you mean when you say "after modifying that iso image can't stay bootable"?

Comment: I want to say that after changing in any file of iso i burn it on DVD that DVD can't be boot to use that live os

Comment: If you tell us how you changed the file, how you created the new ISO file, etc. then we might be able to help.

Comment: I changed isolinux.cfg file using notepad++ after that when i burn that into DVD it's not stay bootable.

Comment: aaron It's nice of you that after 2 year you reply on this question. Thanks

Comment: How do you burn the DVD? Do you create an ISO file? Which tools do you use?

Comment: I used Magic ISO for it

Comment: Read the documentation how to create bootable CDs. They have a special format, simply putting files into the ISO won't magically do what you want.